# Install the Intl library in php on a windows system EasyPhp 14

Tags: php, easyphp, intl

I've to install a PHP extension on my system, (it is already installed on the host system machine but I've reinstalled the system so it is not working any more on my Windows machine). I've `EasyPHP` installed as a `WAMP` engine and the module `intl.dll` is not loaded and not present in the installation. I've read many manuals but most of them are for debian machine and not for Windows, or fo older version of `EasyPHP`.

My `phpinfo();` doesn't give any sign of intl library to be installed.

Thank you for any help

UPDATE
The file php_intl.dll is existent in the system and is placed in

```
binaries/php/ext
```

But when i try to uncommeent the line:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

it gives me some error saying that it cannot find the 
    icuuc49.dll

But it is existent in the ext directory of php (I've already placed it there) so where should i place this file?

Comment: This is how i've managed to do it, i've added all the series of icu*.dll file to the c:WINDOWS path, as the path of php was already added to the system but whasn't working in any manner. Hope this helps..

Comment: Copying the icu* files from /php to apache/bin/ folder worked for me, without editing path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. rightclick EasyPHP icon
2. configuration > php
3. find line like:

   ;extension=php_intl.dll
4. remove ";" (uncomment the line)
5. restart easyphp

if the problem is that there is not `php_intl.dll` file in your

```
EasyPHP\binaries\php\php_runningversion\ext
```

folder, just get it from somewhere and add it to the folder, then add the line

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

under extensions section of php config in easyPHP

If you get missing files errors, those file are probably in the  EasyPHP\binaries\php  so you have to add this directory to yout PATH system variable, you can check how to do it here:
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm